# Using PHP to set up SSH connection and SFTP

Tags: php, ssh, ftp, sftp

I'm trying to set up a `ssh` connection, and later a `sftp` connection to transfer file via FTP to my server. I have used FileZilla to upload files successfully before.

These are my login terminal command and FileZilla login information:

```
ssh b0xxxxx@linux7.aa.bb.cc.dd
Host: sftp://linux7.aa.bb.cc.dd
Username: b0xx
Port: 22
```

Here is my `php` code:

```
<?php
    $ftp_server = "b0xx@linux7.aa.bb.cc.dd";
    $ftp_port = 22; 
    $ftp_user = "b0xx";
    $ftp_pass = "##";
    $connection = ssh2_connect($ftp_server, $ftp_port);
    echo "Successful!\n";
    if (ssh2_auth_password($connection, $ftp_user, $ftp_pass)) {
      echo "Successful\n";
    } else {
      die ('Failed...');
    }
    $sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);
    ssh2_scp_send($connection, '/local/filename', '/remote/filename', 0644);

?>
```

Question 1: Can I just use `ftp` functions to upload/download file from my server?
Or do I must set up `ssh`?

Question 2: When I execute the code, the website only displays

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
```

which means that the code does not execute `connection` successfully. Does anyone know the cause of the bug?

Very much appreciate the help.

Comment: Have you checked the php error log file for related messages?

Answer (score 0):

Seems SSH2 PECL extension is not installed. Install the extension and then try your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ftp_server = "b0xx@linux7.aa.bb.cc.dd";
```

"b0xx@linux7.aa.bb.cc.dd" isn't a hostname. Hostnames can't have "@" in them. This is probably intended to be a "username@hostname" string, but `ssh_connect()` doesn't accept a string in this form.

Remove the username portion:

```
$ftp_server = "linux7.aa.bb.cc.dd";
```